# How can I create some Paperclip objects from a Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a model `Idea` which `has_attached_file :file1` and `has_attached_file :file2`. For development purposes, I have a "bootstrap" task which is responsible of creating some initial objects ( just so that you don't have to create a user, then upload some files each and every time we delete the sqlite file ). How should I do this from a Rake task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Idea.new(
  :name => 'bla',
  :file1 => File.open('/some/path/to.file'),
  :file2 => File.open('/some/path/to.file')
)
```